# Loading Bootstrap pill content on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, zend-framework

I currently have a page that has four Bootstrap pill tabs. The content associated with each of these tabs are fairly large tables.  Because of this upon loading the site, all of the content is loading making it very slow.  I would like to change it so that the table for each tab is not loaded until the person switches to that tab.  How can I accomplish this?

---

The links to each tab are as follows:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active"><a href="#active_projects"
                data-toggle="tab">Active Projects</a></li>

    <li><a href="#archived_projects" data-toggle="tab">Archived
                    Projects</a></li>

    <li><a href="#active_families" data-toggle="tab">Active Families</a> </li>

    <li><a href="#archived_families" data-toggle="tab">Archived Families</a> </li>
</ul>
```

Next, I have the four `divs` that are loading the content:

```
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="active_projects" class="tab-pane active"
            style="margin-bottom: 80px;">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <table class="table table-hover">
                    <?php echo $headers; ?>
                    <?php if (isset($this->active)) : ?>
                    <?php echo $this->partialLoop('project/project/projectSummary.phtml',  $this->active) ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="archived_projects" class="tab-pane"
            style="margin-bottom: 80px;">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <table class="table table-hover">
                    <?php echo $headers; ?>
                    <?php if (isset($this->archived)) : ?>
                    <?php echo $this->partialLoop('project/project/projectSummary.phtml', $this->archived) ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="active_families" class="tab-pane"
            style="margin-bottom: 80px;">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <table class="table table-hover">
                    <?php echo $family_headers; ?>
                    <?php if (isset($this->active_families)) : ?>
                    <?php echo $this->partialLoop('projectFamily/projectFamily/familySummary.phtml', $this->active_families) ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="archived_families" class="tab-pane"
            style="margin-bottom: 80px;">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <table class="table table-hover">
                    <?php echo $family_headers; ?>
                    <?php if (isset($this->archived_families)) : ?>
                    <?php echo $this->partialLoop('projectFamily/projectFamily/familySummary.phtml', $this->archived_families) ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

The Zend Framework is used to create the tables. The tab content is changed with JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // If a tab is specified by an anchor tag, activate it
    // See: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/2415#issuecomment-4589184
    $(function () {
        var activeTab = $('[href=' + location.hash + ']');
        activeTab && activeTab.tab('show');
    });
</script>
```

---

## What I'm trying

I'm thinking I can use JQuery `load()`.  I can get the basic idea working with something along the lines of `document.getElementById("active_projects").innerHTML = ""` but this requires a string, making the code not particularly nice.  Any ideas?

Comment: You need use `AJAX` for loading data of tabs if need.

Comment: @newage can you give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need use `AJAX` for loading data for tab if it selected.
For example:

HTML part

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active">
        <a href="#" class="active_projects" data-toggle="tab">Active Projects</a>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

Another part of HTML

```
<div id="active_projects" class="tab-pane active" style="margin-bottom: 80px;">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <!-- Data from AJAX query will insert here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

JQuery part (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

```
$(".active_projects").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "/controller/action/active_projects"
    })
    .done(function( msg ) {
        alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
    });
});
```

In PHP need create action with `JSON` response

```
public function loadAction()
{
    $view = JsonModel();
    $view->addValues(["table" => "this will table data"]);
    return $view;
}
```